# CSS table with center align and max-height

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to show an image centered in window (horizontally & vertically). If the image is too large, I want to scale it down to fit (no scrollbars).

Here is a live [demo](http://jsbin.com/sugikisuxugi) - try resizing the window. The image scales to fit but is not vertically centered.

I am trying to use CSS `table`/`table-cell`, but this breaks `max-height` set on the image. If you uncomment the `table`/`table-cell`, the image will extend beyond bottom of window.

Is it possible to have both? I've found similar questions but not this exact setup.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sugikisuxugi/2/edit

Comment: @Alohci Wow this is defo a solution, I will hold out to see if it's possible with css table otherwise I'll accept this…

Answer (score 0):

I used `vh` and `vw` to capture the viewport dimensions. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ta96h577/) sort of what you want?

Comment: Cool idea and nice cat! If I resize the img can stretch horizontally beyond the window though?

Comment: @MachineElf Is the image not being constrained in the fiddle I linked to? It's working for me. The image is being constrained both horizontally and vertically for me.

Comment: Sorry I was testing in Firefox, seems to work in Webkit, I'm getting some odd behaviour when resizing browser but I'm not sure if it's an issue with JSFiddle/Bin site frames? I'll try it on desktop… thx a lot